# Preforming 2 async functions on success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a case where I create a new user via ajax call, and after the user is created (server returns 200), I immediately update it again with ajax.

Now I can do it in a stupid way where I have the ajax call written 2 times:

1. When I create the user
2. Inside the `success:` of the first ajax

That way the call is synchronous.
I'm looking for a more elegant way of preforming this ajax call, preferably where the `ajax` is inside a function that recieves `url` and `data` values and then call itself when the first execution is successful.

This is what I have now:

```
var requests = [
    {url: 'addNewUser', data: ''},
    {url: 'updateUser', data: ''}
];    
requests[0].data = JSON.stringify(formData);
formData.roles = "4,2,30";
requests[1].data = JSON.stringify(formData);
for(var k=0;k<requests.length;k++){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: apiURL + requests[k].url,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: requests[k].data,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data + " success");
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log("error " + data);
        },
        done: function(data) {
            console.log(data + " success");
        }
    });
}
```

Right now, the `updateUser` finishes before the `addNewUser`, but it fails because there's no user to update.

Comment: Read about callbacks functions, promises or async/await. This is what you need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a `for` loop; instead, use the callback from an earlier call to start the next call (see `***` lines). Also note that there is no `done` option for `$.ajax`; there's a `done` *function* you can call on `$.ajax` result, but for what we're using below, we want the `complete` option:

```
var requests = [
    {url: 'addNewUser', data: ''},
    {url: 'updateUser', data: ''}
];    
requests[0].data = JSON.stringify(formData);
formData.roles = "4,2,30";
requests[1].data = JSON.stringify(formData);
var k = 0;
doOne();                                    // ***
function doOne() {                          // ***
    if (k >= requests.length) {
        return;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: apiURL + requests[k].url,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: requests[k].data,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data + " success");
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log("error " + data);
        },
        complete: function(data) {          // ***
            console.log(data + " complete");// ***
            ++k;                            // ***
            doOne();                        // ***
        }
    });
}
```

If you only want the "loop" to continue when earlier calls are successful, move the `++k;` and `doOne();` calls from `complete` to `success`.